# how to return text to when particular option is selected from dropdown list

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, webforms

My code consists of drop down list from which any option is selected then others must filled auotmatically

```
         <td>Annual Income</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">100000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">50000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">25000</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4">10000</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Basic Pay</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HRA</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tax</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
```

This code where `annual income` is selected from the drop down list then basic and hra must be auto selected

Comment: basic and HRA auto selected but its a text box? what you mean by that?

Comment: No, annual income is in drop down list so if I select particular value then it should hra  and basic must be displayed

Comment: what value is annual income.. so HRA and basic or hidden to start off with?

Comment: Can I use code behind to return values using dropdownlist_onselectedchange event??

Comment: I couldn't get you...@JoshStevens

Comment: yes you can use that.. if you tell me what you actually need to do i can help.. i see dropdown has values once selected annual income what needs to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Add this function in server side (assuming C#)

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("1"))
    {
        TextBox3.Text = "10000";
        TextBox4.Text = "500";
    }
}
```

Comment: can I use if contd to display particular results